# What will be the general value of $\tan\left(\frac{π}{4} - X\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry

We know that 
$$\sin\left(\frac{π}{2} - X\right) = \cos X,$$
$$\cos(π - X) = -\cos X$$
$$\tan\left(\frac{π}{2} + X\right) = -\cot X \text{ etc.}$$
Is there any trigonometric identity for $\tan\left(\frac{π}{4} - X\right)$ ? If there is any solution please elaborate the procedure.

Comment: You can use the sum and difference formula for $\tan$, but it won't be as pretty as the one's you listed.

Comment: Welcome to mathematics stackexchange. have a look at mathjax to improve your mathematical expressions

Answer (score 1):

More generally, it can be shown that$$\sin(A\pm B)=\sin A\cos B\pm \sin B\cos A=\cos A\cos B(\tan A\pm\tan B)$$and$$\cos(A\pm B)=\cos A\cos B\mp\sin A\sin B=\cos A\cos B(1\mp\tan A\tan B)$$so$$\tan(A\pm B)=\frac{\sin(A\pm B)}{\cos(A\pm B)}=\frac{\tan A\pm\tan B}{1\mp\tan A\tan B}.$$In particular,$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)=\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)=\cot(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)=\frac{\cot(x)-1}{\cot(x)+1}$$